# Handlebars, how to set a condition for a value returned by a helper

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm using a handlebar helper for calculating how many rows there is in an array. If it's above 2 it returns true, and it works as it's suppose to. Looks like this:

```
define('templates/helpers/countRows', ['handlebars'], function ( Handlebars ) {
    function countRows(selectedArray) {
        var selectedArrayLength = selectedArray.length;
        if (parseInt(selectedArrayLength) > 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    Handlebars.registerHelper('countRows', countRows);
    return countRows;
});
```

The problem is that I want to set a condition in my hbs template to check if the value is true or not before outputting it. If it isn't true, I don't want it to output. I was hoping I could do something like this:

```
{{#if countRows "my array"}}
    markup that only gets displayed if value is true
{{/if}}
```

But this isn't valid unfortunately..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach would be to define computed properties on your controller to handle this type of logic.

```
App.ThingsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  enoughRows: Ember.computed.gte('content.length', 2)
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#if enoughRows}}
  ...
{{/if}}
```

Having logic like this embedded in a template is hard to debug and test. Following this philosophy, handlebars makes it hard to do condition checks outside of true/false.

If you need to repeat this kind of logic in many controllers, consider making a mixin.

```
App.EnoughRowsMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
  enoughRows: Ember.computed.gte('content.length', 2)
});
```